# PHP $_POST vars empty with Bootstrap Forms

Tags: php, mysql, forms, twitter-bootstrap, post

I'm having trouble figuring out what is wrong here. I have Bootstrap 3.0.

My **form.php**

```
        <form role="form" action="../../sgm/leadinsert" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fName" name="fName" placeholder="Enter first name" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lName" name="lName" placeholder="Enter last name" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pNo">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pNo" name="pNo" placeholder="Ex: 555-555-5555" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comm">Comments</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comm" name="comm" placeholder="Enter any comments here; max size 500 chars."></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Next"/>
              </div>
    </form>
```

Here is my **leadinsert.php**

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
$fName = $_POST[ "fName" ];
$lName = $_POST[ "lName" ];
$pNo = $_POST[ "pNo" ];
$email = $_POST[ "email" ];
$comm = $_POST[ "comm" ];

$sql="INSERT INTO Leads (fName, lName, pNo, email, comm)
VALUES ('$fName', '$lName', '$pNo', '$email', '$comm')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con) . print_r($_POST));
 }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Note: on my action= I have my .htaccess set to interpret that. I have never had a problem getting forms to submit to my db, until I implemented bootstrap. It is submitting to my db table, but it is an empty row.

Comment: First: you're a perfect target for sql injections. Second: Please post the output of `var_dump($_POST);` inserted in your insert.php.

Comment: Using Firebug or Developer tools can you confirm that you're posting values correctly?

Comment: @Tjati So my whole goal with this is lead generation. Basically I want to be emailed whenever a new user gives me their info on my site. Also here is the var_dump($_POST) array(0) { }

Comment: @UTDguy: this was not expected. the output should containt your posted values. have you filled in the fields of your form? could you please change your action-path to action="leadinsert.php", repost and post your new output of var_dump($_POST)

Comment: @Tjati Oh wow... that was the problem. Thank you so much for your input.

Answer (score 0):

in your action you have this file

```
 action="../../sgm/leadinsert"
```

while you provide insert.php ?

you should have this

```
  action="path/insert.php"
```

and also you forgot  `value = ''` in all your inputs , write them like that:

```
<input type="text" value=""  class="form-control" id="fName" name="fName" placeholder="Enter first name" />
```

Comment: S/He wrote, he's using .htaccess. I assume s/he means mod_rewrite.

Comment: Adding value="" did not help, and that was a typo in my question, so the action path wasn't the problem.

Comment: @echo_Me Per Tjati's suggestion I put var_dump($_POST) in my php file, it returns array(0) {}

Comment: @echo_Me nothing is returned.

Comment: you have this in your input `value = ''` and you got nothing printed of the variable above `echo $_POST[ "fName" ] ;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Bootstrap shouldn't play any effect onto how you process forms, since Bootstrap is simply a template of css and javascript. I would place some checks in your insert.php such as issets and see if there is actually any information in the posts. You can also check this in the Chrome Developer Console.

Comment: Yeah that is what I am saying, there shouldn't be any problem due to bootstrap, but I have never had this issue before implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct you from action then it will work

Comment: It was a typo in my question, I do have my php as leadinsert.php

Answer (score 0):

missing `</div>` and the action as already said

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Next"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I added the end </div>, it did not fix it.